# How to typedef a template class with typdef name C++

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, typename

I have this `typedef`:

```
typedef uint16_t MCPhysReg;
```

and I want to declare (in another file):

```
typedef MapVector<unsigned, MCPhysReg> ConsecRegsMap;
```

`MapVector` is a template class (from another file):

```
template<typename KeyT, typename ValueT,
         typename MapType = llvm::DenseMap<KeyT, unsigned>,
         typename VectorType = std::vector<std::pair<KeyT, ValueT> > >
class MapVector {
...
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> syntax error: missing ';' before '<'

any ideas?

Comment: Feels like MapVector is incomplete when you're typedefing it. Is it included before you typedef it? Can you try defining a class with a MapVector in it instead of typedef? Just to make sure it's a complete type.

Comment: Present your [MCVE]

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So include that other file in this one, otherwise how would your compiler know at all what `MapVector` is?